# How do the ways to declare visibility/access in C++ differ?

Tags: c++, class, methods, attributes, visibility

This may be a silly question, but is there any difference in terms of efficiency, optimization etc in how you can declare access in classes in C++?

As a specific example is it more efficient, less efficient, or neither to declare visibility for each attribute/method in a class vs declaring visibility (i.e. private/public/protected) "blocks" in classes.

For example, is the following code:

```
class Foo{
  private:
    int member1;
    string member2;
    ...
    Thing memberN;

  public:
    int member2;
    Thing member3;
    ...
    string memberM;
}
```

more efficient than:

```
class Foo{
  private:
    int member1;

  private:
    string member2;

  private:
    ...

  private:
    Thing memberN;

  public:
    int member2;

  public:
    Thing member3;

  public:
    ...

  public:
    string memberM;


}
```

Comment: Test it out. Use a timer and a profile to check if there is a difference, Or just compare the assembler outputs of both methods.

Comment: My understanding is that accessibility is a compile time concept and there is no code emitted to enforce the accessibility.  For example, private members can be accessed via pointers (not clean, violates many things, but doable).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same. Access modifiers are for compiler usage and result in the same output binary code.

Comment: What about the time it takes to compile?

Comment: @thed0ctor it's up to a compiler implementation. In case of multiple modifiers instead of one it's theoretically a bit slower but this is completely insignificant